# Paper form - how to present opt out options

Tags: checkboxes, many-options, paper

I have a paper form that is quite complex where customers filling up the form tends to gloss over the options and just submit without going through all the details. This causes an operational headache and backlogs in paper forms not properly filled up. The current form requires the customers to tick one by one of the functions they require, which is quite tedious. So what they tend to do is to tick everything for fear that they miss out something.

One solution is to lump all the functions to a few basic packages, and defaulting the packages. After selecting a package, the customer has the choice to opt out the service which they don't want, e.g. below

[image]

However, here are a few questions I have
1) whilst opt out is fine on the computer screen, how to do that on a paper form?
2) should i use a tick for check box, or use a cross to opt out for a service?

rgsd

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user to strike out any unwanted option - this avoids the ambiguity of ticking a checkbox to remove an item, and is very easy and familiar on paper:

[image: Paper mockup with strikeouts]

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea of offering three basic option groups, as it reduces the amount of thought the end user has to spend.  It works for cars, iPhones, just about anything.  If you want to offer a fourth, "a la carte" option, be careful that your regular users don't jump to it by default.

You might show it like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff9Vl1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I usually see the "opt in/out" check box set in a separate paragraph at the end, near the place where the customer would be required to sign the form to indicate they agree to it.